# DevExpress ASP.net Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Guys i am having a problem running my Devexpress 15.2 web app on my IIS server locally on windows 10 after suceessfully publishing it. i get the following error message :

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070021
Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File    \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/MyApplication
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AppFolder
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Config Source:
   61:   
   62:     
   63:

More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
View more information »

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  Here is how I fixed it...

Use the run command to run appwiz.xpl

Click on Turn Windows features on or off

Expand World Wide Web Services, Expand Application Development Features, and check the boxes ASP.NET 3.5 and/or ASP>NET 4.6 depending on which version you are targeting.

Click ok

Restart IIS Server.

Hope this helps.